# SAPUI5 draw google chart in newly created control (panel) by click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, sapui5

I haven't a lot of experience with JS. But currently I have task in which I need create HTML page and display there google charts on Panels (SAPUI5 control).
Page build with SAPUI5 elements:

```
Vertical layout
|- Panel #1 (open)
|  |- Grid layout
|     |- Panel with google chart 1
|     |- Panel with google chart 2
|     |- Panel . . .
|     |- Panel with google chart N
|- Panel #2 (closed / collapsed)
|- Panel #3 (closed / collapsed)
|- . . .
|- Panel #M (closed / collapsed)
```

I have no problems in implementing that logic. Page is loading and charts are drawing successfully.
Next step is implement logic of drawing charts when user open any of closed Panels. I do this with function:

```
function pressedCollapseButton(oControlEvent) {
  var panelID = oControlEvent.getParameter("id");
  panelID = cutFromString(panelID, (panelID.length - sufixClpsBtn.length), panelID.length);
  var oPanel = sap.ui.getCore().byId(panelID);
  if (!oPanel.getCollapsed()) {
    oPanel.setCollapsed(true);
  } else {
    oPanel.setCollapsed(false);
    if ( oPanel.getContent().length == 0 ) {
      // no GridLayout in main Panel; recive data and create new controls
      $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: urlSAP,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          "lt" : "additional",
          "tgid" : panelID
        },
        success: function(oData){processData_2(oPanel, oData)}
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In function "processData_2" I create GridLayout and some number of Panels based on received data.

```
function processData_2(oTileGroup, oDAB) {
  var arrayOfIDs = []; // chart ID (index) and div ID (array element value) where chart should be placed
  var oGridTiles = new sap.ui.layout.Grid({hSpacing: 1, vSpacing: 1});
  var oTile;
  // create panels using received data
  for (var i = 0; i < oDAB.elems.length; i++)
  {
    switch (oDAB.elems[i].type) {
      case ("TILE"):
        oTile = crtElement_Tile(oDAB.elems[i].title);
        arrayOfIDs[oDAB.elems[i].id] = String(oTile).split("#")[1] + "-cont";
        oGridTiles.addContent(oTile);
      break;
    }
  }
  oTileGroup.addContent(oGridTiles);
  startChartDrawing(oDAB.user, oDAB.elems, arrayOfIDs, false);
}
```

But in function "startChartDrawing" script sends "Uncaught Error: Container is not defined" for line

```
chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(arr[oCharts[i].id]));
```

As I understand new Panels yet not added to page when I try to draw there charts. Please help find a solution. Maybe there is some event which occurs when all controls fully created.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution that works fine for me. Last line of function processData_2 I replaced with

```
oTileGroup.addContent(oLayout);
var handler = function(){
  $(document).unbind('DOMNodeInserted.myEvent');
  startChartDrawing(oDAB.elems, arrayOfIDs, false);
};
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted.myEvent', handler);
```